# Laravel - installation of doctrine/dbal failed

Tags: laravel, doctrine, composer-php

I am trying to install doctrine/dbal on a legacy code that I am working with. On trying to run the `composer require doctrine/dbal` I get the error:

> [RuntimeException]
>   Could not scan for classes inside "app/Libs" which does not appear to
>   be a file nor a folder

This is the composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "jgrossi/corcel": "^1.4",
        "ellipsesynergie/api-response": "^0.12.3",
        "corcel/acf": "^0.1.12"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database",
            "app/Libs"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: You say `app\Libraries`, but the error says `app/Libs`, are you sure it's not a typo? Can you update your question with the complete `composer.json`?

Comment: Can you post your `composer.json` file?

Comment: sorry, yes, it is the app/libs

Comment: I have added composer.json to the question

Comment: Remove `app/Libs` from classmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the problem was that you add `app` folder to `psr-4` section and then `app\Libs` to classmap?
Try remove it like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
```

You already say to scan `app` folder and than try scan it again.